# subsystem request failed on channel 0

Tags: scp

When I tried to copy files from linux server using scp like this:

```
> scp root@192.168.50.90:/volume1/DownloadStationStore/containerd-1.6.12-linux-amd64.tar.gz .
subsystem request failed on channel 0
scp: Connection closed
```

what should I do to fixed this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the logs from `192.168.50.90` as to why the subsystem request has failed?  Is `192.168.50.90` configured to allow `scp`?